# env package incompatible with Python 3 being installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, python-3.9

I am using a MacOS 10.15.7. I did brew install python. python -V also result in python 3 version. But when i am installing packages with pip3 then packages written in python2 are getting installed here. What is wrong here? How to fix this?

```
ap@Pro ~ % pip3 install env --no-cache-dir
Collecting env
  Downloading env-0.1.0.tar.gz (1.8 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for env, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: env
    Running setup.py install for env ... done
Successfully installed env-0.1.0

ap@Pro ~ % python3 -m env air               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 158, in _get_module_details
    code = loader.get_code(mod_name)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 923, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 853, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/env.py", line 51
    print k
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(k)?
```

Comment: There is no Python3 version for this package.

Comment: you can install virtualenv and use that

Answer (score 1):

The version of `env` in PyPi isn't compatible with Python 3. The issue appears to have been raised about 3 years ago and fixed in the source, but a new package was never released. You can find the current (apparently Python 3 compatible) source [here](https://github.com/MasterOdin/env). See [this issue](https://github.com/MasterOdin/env/issues/5).